# logstash index a text file (username email password

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'd like to import a text file in Elasticsearch. The text file contains 3 values per line. After spending several hours of struggling, I didn't get it done. Help is greatly appreciated.

Elasticsearch 5.4.0 with Logstash installed.

came up with this pattern: %{WORD:username} %{WORD:email} %{WORD:hash} but i dont understand how to set it up in a config file

Sample data:

```
username email hash
username email hash
username email hash
username email hash
username email hash
```

Comment: Please update your other question instead of posting the same one a second time :-)

Comment: ohh thanks im new to all of this